# Adjusting the size of SmartArt nodes using VBA for PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, powerpoint

I am wondering if there is a way to change the width/height of each individual node of a SmartArt object using VBA in PowerPoint 2010.

I have attempted this using the following code but I end up with an error message:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(2).SmartArt.AllNodes(j).Shapes.Height = 100
```

I found a link to a similar question with Word 2010, and it seems as though the size can not be changed using VBA as the height property is read-only.
http://www.excelforum.com/word-programming-vba-macros/860581-word-2010-smartart-vba-how-to-change-size.html

If anyone knows whether or not there is a possible way to do this in VBA, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It is not the fully the answer but hope it will be helpful. It seems that you can not change width or height of the node individually. But you can make a node larger or smaller in this way:

```
'to enlarge
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(2).SmartArt.AllNodes(j).Larger

'to make it smaller
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(2).SmartArt.AllNodes(j).Smaller
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use scaling and then use the width property to calculate the scaling factor. Disadvantage of this method is that it impacts the object size. I used convert to shapes to handle it. SmartArts are painful.

```
    Node.Shapes.ScaleWidth Application.CentimetersToPoints(4.5) / Node.Shapes.Height, msoFalse
```

The above code will scale your width to 4.5 cm.

Answer (score -2):

You can change it by scaling it (i think):

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(2).SmartArt.AllNodes(j).Shapes.ScaleHeight  1.75, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopToLeft
```

Comment: wrong syntax, `.ScaleHeight` is a method, not property